# to bundle out of the way

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'd like to make sure what " to bundle out of the way" means ? I think it means  cramped in a place that you cannot move so you can nothing to do. there is no way out in figurative and literal sense.

> Once she is coerced into signing adoption papers, **she's bundled out of
>   the way** and into the  convent to save her parents further humiliation.

There are many examples on the internet but not sure whether they are related to this sense.

Comment: If you bundle out of the way, it means you hurriedly move out of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*bundle out* is a phrase used to mean *'expel'*.

Say -

> The bouncer *bundled the drunk man out*

It seems that 'she' in your context is forcefully asked to sign and sent to the convent for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

"Bundle out of the way" means to forcibly move aside or remove an obstruction or inconvenience, typically a person. So, in your quoted text "she" is forced to enter a nunnery to remove her as an obstruction to her parents' good standing in the community. Judging by the mention of coerced signing of adoption papers, it appears that she had given birth to a child that her parents found socially inconvenient.